# Using results from one MySQL query in another query in a PHP Envirnment

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a problem, it may be a simple fix to the issue, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am new to PHP and MySQL, so I'm reading everything everywhere, but lack of experience is very frustrating, as often times it takes ages to realize a small error.  Please look at the following tables and read below the questions.

The PHP/mysql is in Joomla environment, I am trying to modify a plugin, so that is updates with values from different tables into a set of other tables, that were not originally intended, but all tables reside in the same database.

```
   Table 1           vm_orders
---------------------------------------------
order_id    user_id     
---------------------------------------------
20          1           
55          6           
65          2           
30          4           
50          67          




   Table 2   vm_order_item
---------------------------------------------
order_item_id   order_id  order_item_sku    
---------------------------------------------
20                  20          1
55                  55          35
65                  65          60
30                  30          22
50                  50          3



Table 3 xipt_ users
---------------------------------------------------
userid  Profiletype template
----------------------------------------------------
1       1       default
6       3       default
2       1       default
4       8       default
67      7       default


Table 4      community_fields_values
---------------------------------------------
id      user_id     field_id    value
---------------------------------------------
1           1           55      Female
2           6           35      Cat
3           2           2       2
4           4           18      Texas
5           67          12      bike
```

What I need to is first of all get the order number according to the user that has place the order.
The userid variable is being passed from elsewhere in the script. That part is working fine.
So the user 67 has placed an order. These are the things I want to achieve.

1. Query 1:  I want to get the "orderid" value from "order_id" column of vm_orders table (table 1); i will call the result "vmorderid" and use it in another             query.
2. Query 2:  Using the "vmorderid" from query 1 as the order_id value in the "order_id" column of vm_order_item table (table 2). 
              I want to get the order_item_sku value from the "order_item_sku" column of my_order_item table (table 2).
              I will call the result "vmsku" and use it in another query.
3. Query 3:  Using the "vmsku" from query 2 as the profiletype value in the "Profiletype" column of vm_users table (table 3).
              I want to UPDATE  the value of the "profiletype" column, with "vmsku" value.
4. Query 4:  Using the "vmsku" from query 2 as the value in the "value" column of    community_fields_values (table 4). 
               I want to UPDATE the value of the "value" column in  my_fields_values (table 4) "vmsku" value.

Okay, I hope you are with me so far, I have tried a couple of queries, but it's not working. 
Here is what I have so far:

Assuming the user it is being passed from a param field.

```
$userid = $this->params->get('userid', 'defaultValue'); 




function _vm_custom_order($vmorderId) 
{

    $vmorderId = $database->loadResult();
    $database = JFactory::getDBO();

    // query the db to see if the user is already a member of group

     $vmorderId ="

                SELECT MAX
                    `order_id` 
                FROM 
                    #__vm_orders';
                WHERE 
                    `user_id` = '{$userid}'
                    ";

     $database->setQuery( $vmorderId );
    $data = $database->loadResult();

    return $data;
}



function _vm_sku($vmsku) 
{

    $vmsku = $database->loadResult();
    $database = JFactory::getDBO();

    // query the db to see if the user is already a member of group
    $vmsku = "
                SELECT 
                    `product_sku` 
                FROM 
                    #__vm_order_item';
                WHERE 
                    `order_id` = '{$vmorderId}'

                    ";

      $database->setQuery( $vmsku );
    $data = $database->loadResult();

    return $data;

}



function _add( $userid, $groupid, $vmsku)
{
    $success = false;
    $database = JFactory::getDBO();

    if (!$allow_multiplegroups = $this->params->get( 'allow_multiplegroups', '1' )) {
        // query the db to see if the user is already a member of ANY group
        $database->setQuery("
            SELECT 
                `profiletype` 
            FROM 
                #__xipt_users
            WHERE 
                `userid` = '{$userid}' 
        ");
        $member = $database->loadResult();

        // if so, do not execute
        if (intval($member) > 0) {
            return $success;
        }
    }

    $already = plgAmbrasubsAddToXipt::_already( $userid, $groupid );

    if (($already != $userid)) 
    {
    $database->setQuery("

                SELECT MAX
                    `order_id` 
                FROM 
                    #__vm_orders
                WHERE 
                    `user_id` = '{$userid}'
                        ");

                    $vmorderId = $database->loadResult();

        if ($database->query()) {
            $success = true; 
        }
    }       


    if (($already != $userid)) 
    {

$database->setQuery("

                SELECT 
                    `product_sku` 
                FROM 
                    #__vm_order_item
                WHERE 
                    `order_id` = '{$vmorderId}'
                        ");                     

                    $vmsku = $database->loadResult();

        if ($database->query()) {
            $success = true; 
        }
    }           


    // if they aren't already a member of the group, add them to the group
    if (($already != $userid)) 
    {
        $database->setQuery("
            UPDATE 
                #__xipt_users
            SET
                `profiletype` = '{$vmsku}'

            WHERE
                `userid` = '{$userid}'

            LIMIT 1

        ");

        if ($database->query()) {
            $success = true; 
        }
    } 

    return $success;
}

}
```

I also tried it this way:

```
function _add( $userid, $groupid, $vmsku)
{
    $success = false;
    $database = JFactory::getDBO();

    if (!$allow_multiplegroups = $this->params->get( 'allow_multiplegroups', '1' )) {
        // query the db to see if the user is already a member of ANY group
        $database->setQuery("
            SELECT 
                `profiletype` 
            FROM 
                #__xipt_users
            WHERE 
                `userid` = '{$userid}' 
        ");
        $member = $database->loadResult();

        // if so, do not execute
        if (intval($member) > 0) {
            return $success;
        }
    }

    $already = plgAmbrasubsAddToXipt::_already( $userid, $groupid );

    if (($already != $userid)) 
    {
    $database->setQuery("

                SELECT MAX
                    `order_id` 
                FROM 
                    #__vm_orders
                WHERE 
                    `user_id` = '{$userid}'
                        ");

                    $vmorderId = $database->loadResult();

        if ($database->query()) {
            $success = true; 
        }
    }       


    if (($already != $userid)) 
    {

$database->setQuery("

                SELECT 
                    `product_sku` 
                FROM 
                    #__vm_order_item
                WHERE 
                    `order_id` = '{$vmorderId}'
                        ");                     

                    $vmsku = $database->loadResult();

        if ($database->query()) {
            $success = true; 
        }
    }           



    // if they aren't already a member of the group, add them to the group
    if (($already != $userid)) 
    {
        $database->setQuery("
            UPDATE 
                #__xipt_users
            SET
                `profiletype` = '{$vmsku}'

            WHERE
                `userid` = '{$userid}'


            LIMIT 1

        ");

        if ($database->query()) {
            $success = true; 
        }
    } 

    return $success;
}

}
```

EDIT: I have now tried as suggested, to use JOIN to accomplish the task,  so far no joy!

> UPDATE

```
                        #__xipt_users

                    SET
                        `profiletype.#__xipt_users` = `product_sku.#__vmsku`

                    WHERE

                        `userid` = '{$userid}'


                    AND                         

                    ( 
                     SELECT `order_id.#__vm_orders`
                           FROM #__vm_orders, #__vm_order_item
                            LEFT JOIN #__vm_orders 
                            ON #__vm_orders.`order_id` = #__vm_order_item.`order_id` 
                            ORDER BY `order_id.#__vm_order` DESC LIMIT 1
                            WHERE
                            `user_id.#__vm_orders` = '{$userid}'

                    ) AS #__vmorder_id


                     SELECT ` product_sku.#__vm_order_item`
                           FROM #__vm_order_item, #__vmorder_id
                            LEFT JOIN #__vm_order_item 
                            ON `#__vm_order_item.order_id` = `#__vmorder_id.order_id` 
                            WHERE
                            `order_id.#__vm_order_item` = `order_id.#__vmorder_id`
                            )

                      AS #__vmsku

                    LIMIT 1

                    ");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Join Statements**
I would suggest you start learning how to create Join Statements in MySQL.

Have a look at this website:
http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php

That way you are able to combine multiple queries into one. It will make this job a lot easier!

**Piece of paper**
Also it will help you to draw your database on a piece of paper to get a better overview of what you want to do. For example you can draw lines between the table fields you want to link.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response and also the link, its got lost of useful information, i have been reading through the join and other sections, i have tried best to make sense of it all. I have tried to apply it to my task, but so far no luck, i will continue reading and searching- till i have better grasp of it all. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome. If you have any questions, feel free to ask them!

Comment: well no luck yet, it seems i have it all as it should be, maybe its something to do with the backticks eg. `order_id.#__vm_orders`, in the rest of the script, they use backticks on all column names and none on table names, but for the JOIN we specify column.table so i'm not sure how the backticks should go.

Comment: Do you mean `table.\`column\``?